# Plot aspect ratio

Tags: highcharts

How do you specify the aspect ratio of the plot? I'm working on a dashboard where when you click on a static png chart, it changes into a highchart. The problem is that plot areas of my static chart are more square, while highchart defaults to wider aspect ratio.

Is there any way to specify what aspect ratio I want for the chart without specifying fixed width and height?

EDIT:

to explain better, when I use div as a target of my chart, it fills the width correctly, but height seems to get decided by some kind of aspect ratio variable which I dont know how to change.

EDIT2:

Can I specify for example, for all my charts:

chartHeight = chartWidth * 0.75?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you sure can!

Since you want to have all of the charts in your dashboard to have the same dimensions, I'd suggest the following:

1) Define a basic style that will be shared by all of your container divs. This is where you'll set the width and height that's common to all of them.

```
// in your stylesheet:
.chartStyle {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

<!-- in your HTML code: -->
<div id="container" class="chartStyle"></div>
<div id="container2" class="chartStyle"></div>
```

2) In your chart code, before you set any chart options, set width and height variables that are calculated based on the current dimensions of the first container div (since they all share the same width and height).

```
var myWidth = $('#container').width();
var myHeight = $('#container').width() * 0.75;
```

3) In each chart's options, set the width and height attributes to the variables you declared earlier.

```
chart: {
    width: myWidth,
    height: myHeight
},
```

Now, each chart should render in the aspect ratio you defined.

Here's a fiddle with this setup: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/eaut2jcs/

For bonus points, you can set a `$(window).resize` event to update the width and height variables and redraw the charts if your users change the size of the browser window.

**One thing to be mindful of**: The browser can't accurately calculate the dimensions of hidden div elements. If you use `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` to hide the chart divs before the changeover from static PNG to interactive chart, you may need to set more explicit values vs. percentages when the user clicks on the PNG.